# Managing Makefile in enterprise C++ project which uses git

Tags: c++, git, makefile

I've started a project which is in c++. I have a team about 6 and all of my team use Netbeans for developing c++. We use stash(git) for managing codes and make pull request for adding codes to repository.
By passing time we are facing a big problem in our pull request and managing make files.
Netbeans builds a configuration.xml file and two different make file for debug and release. When each member of team adds a file or change compiling setting all of these files changes and when his/her codes merges to master branch all other branches get conflict in make files and configuration. I think this should be a usual problem in enterprise projects in c++ But I did not found any good solution for that.

I have provided some examples of my conflicts:

```
<<<<<<<
            <pElem>include/gmock</pElem>
            <pElem>include/gtest</pElem>
=======
            <pElem>/usr/include/ruby-1.9.1/x86_64-linux</pElem>
>>>>>>>
```

Or

```
<<<<<<<
    $(COMPILE.cc) -g -s -Iinclude -I. -Iinclude/X -Iinclude/X/P -I/usr/include/postgresql/9.3/server -I/usr/include/ruby-1.9.1 -Iinclude/dbo/W-Iinclude/log4cxx -Iinclude/gmock -Iinclude/gtest -I. -Iinclude/log4cxx -std=c++11 `cppunit-config --cflags` -MMD -MP -MF "$@.d" -o ${TESTDIR}/tests/Y.o tests/Z.cpp
=======
    $(COMPILE.cc) -g -s -Iinclude -I. -Iinclude/X-Iinclude/X/P -I/usr/include/postgresql/9.3/server -I/usr/include/ruby-1.9.1 -Iinclude/dbo/W-Iinclude/log4cxx -I/usr/include/ruby-1.9.1/x86_64-linux -I. -std=c++11 `cppunit-config --cflags` -MMD -MP -MF "$@.d" -o ${TESTDIR}/tests/Y.o tests/Z.cpp
>>>>>>>
```

Does anyone has a good solution for this problem?

Comment: If netbeans generates your config files, and makefiles maybe you should add those files in the `.gitignore` so that they won't be pushed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is usually not a good practice to manage generated files in a version control system. Reverting this in your case can be difficult so I see the following approaches to your problem:

1. Remove the generated makefiles from git. Instead only add to git the Netbeans project file, and have developers generate the rest from that. This still has the disadvantage that since you are using an IDE like NetBeans, the project file is still a generated file. Conflicts will happen anyway. Developers may try to fix the conflicts, but this is an error-prone task and there is no way for them to know if thet really got it right because the project file's format is only known to NetBeans's developers, users of the IDE should not have to deal with it.
2. Instead of NetBeans use another tool to organize the build. There are several tools that generate makefiles for you, like CMake or autoconf. Others like SCons don't use makefiles and instead are based on python scripts. How adequate these tools are depends on the scale, requirements and availability of your particular project. What these tools have in common is that your create some file or set of files that define your project (i.e. what files compose it) with a syntax defined by the tool. This is what you put in git, not the files generated from it. And these files are under your control so when conflicts happen you know how to fix them.
3. If the project is small, you could even craft a Makefile by hand and put this makefile in git.

In any case keep in mind that conflicts on the project configuration are bound to happen, you can't avoid this. What you can is try to make the condlicts easier to manage.

I personally work in C++ and don't even use and IDE. We use GCC, organize the project with SCons, and edit with an external editor like vim or Sublime Text.

Comment: "I personally work in C++ and don't even use and IDE. We use GCC, organize the project with SCons, and edit with an external editor like vim or Sublime Text." - basically what everyone should do, +42